# Return and embed image with pure javascript , like php?

Tags: php, javascript, image, cross-domain, embed

I'm having trouble figuring out if it's possible to embed an html or js document as an image, like so:

```
<img src="http://blah.com/image.js" />
```

or

```
<img src="http://blah.com/image.html" />
```

The general idea being that when the browser tries to access the file, it would execute the file clientside and get the actual image, and would then embed it as usual. I realize this can be done easily with PHP, but I'm looking for a non-server solution.

Problems being the content type it transfers as is wrong, and more importantly I think this violates every crossdomain and sandbox rule, to which I don't think there's any way around.

Comment: As long as the source you are querying can send a binary output this will work.

Comment: Thing is, I can't figure out how to make the js/html document actually return binary data, everything I've tried results in some form of type error or illegal return. My php train of thought doesn't seem to transfer much to javascript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as the document you are linking to can display the binary data this will work.

Follow this article to solve the binary load with javascript, http://emilsblog.lerch.org/2009/07/javascript-hacks-using-xhr-to-load.html

Then you can also include base64 data in img tags like this

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,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" />
```

Answer (score 2):

The `src` attribute must point to a URI that *eventually* results in actual image data. Perhaps you should consider leaving it blank and then creating a script that generates a [`data:` URI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme) and replaces it into the attribute.

Comment: I'm unable to use any form of javascript on the page I'm linking from

Comment: So... you don't want to run it on the server, and you can't run it on the client. This then brings up one very interesting question: **Where do you expect this JavaScript to run?**

Comment: I figured the scripting would run on the clientside via the image tag trying to pull it, I'm not very familiar with execution parameters in browsers

Comment: The browser expects an image, not a script.

Comment: So my original thinking that this was impossible to do in JS was correct, and I do in fact need a php proxy

Comment: You *can* do it with JavaScript. You *can't* use JavaScript code as an image.

Comment: My point was that it's not possible to do with remote JS like php ( which was my question )

Comment: Yes you can. But you need to use a JavaScript engine on the server.

Comment: Now you're just being nitpicky and ignoring the spirit of the question :p